# iPhone NSDictionary objectForKey: vs valueForKey: performance

Tags: iphone, nsdictionary

In a code base I work with method `valueForKey:` is often used instead of `objectForKey:`. I have to optimize few methods that does this and was thinking if changing this to `objectForKey:` will introduce some performance gains?

Answer (score 1):

For NSDictionary i would use objectForKey:..

valueForKey: redirects to objectForKey if the key does not start with @ and calls [super valueForKey:] if it does..

using find & replace you can change to objectForKey pretty fast so why not, but i doubt you will notice any difference at all!